# set PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel for whole application?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In WPF, is it possible to set the PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel for the whole application rather than having to set it for each individual binding? I'm using my own TraceListener to log binding errors, and my goal is to get a little more information out, especially the default value information.

Comment: AFAIK you can only set it on each binding. If you set it at the global app level this could result in a mass of debug info that's very hard to sort through. I hope someone can confirm or deny this app level setting for you.